# Python -- too many values to unpack

Tags: python, deep-learning

I have this code

```
N, D = x.shape
running_mean = bn_param.get('running_mean', np.zeros(D, dtype=x.dtype))
running_var = bn_param.get('running_var', np.zeros(D, dtype=x.dtype))
```

and it's said: ValueError: too many values to unpack

I know that x has 50x3x32x32 dimension
And I want to put the 50 in N variable and I need to put 3x32x32 in D variable.
How could I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x.shape` has more than 2 values, not matching with the number of variables to unpack (multiple assignment):

```
>>> shape = (50, 3, 32, 32)
>>> N, D = shape
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

You can use index, slice operators to get what you want:

```
>>> shape = (50, 3, 32, 32)
>>> N, D = shape[0], shape[1:]  # [0] to get 1st, [1:] to get 2nd, 3rd,.. up to end
>>> N
50
>>> D
(3, 32, 32)
```

If you're using Python 3.x, you can use [**Extended iterable unpacking** syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
>>> N, *D = shape
>>> N
50
>>> D
[3, 32, 32]
```